# How to use more than one where condition in update query using query builder in yii framework?

Tags: yii, query-builder

I have used one condition , i.e id   now i need to use id with site_id.

```
$manageData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update($tableName,
        array(
            $columnName=>$newValue,
            'modified_on'=>NOW,
        ),
        $index.'=:id',
        array(':id'=>$id)
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$manageData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update(
        $tableName,
        array(
            $columnName=>$newValue,
            'modified_on'=>NOW,
        ),
        $index.'=:id AND site_id=:site_id',
        array(':id'=>$id, 'site_id'=>$siteId)
    );
```